# How to completely change github user on linux?

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-keys

I've been transitioning to a new git  user I use specifically for work-related commits on my linux machine. I used `git config --global` to change the username and email to my new user, and I uploaded a new set of SSH keys to my new user's github profile. However, when I test the connection using `ssh -T git@github.com`, It still tests the connection as my old user:

"Hi OLD_USER! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access"

What do I need to do to change it to use my new user for all git SSH operations?

Comment: How did you configure `ssh`? It doesn't know anything about your `git` configuration.

Comment: I used this official guide: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

Comment: Do you have older entries in `.ssh/config` which specify the old key? Show the file, please. And explain which identity is which.

Answer (score 0):

If you ssh key is not default key then you need to identify you private key with ssh command.

`ssh -i ~/.ssh/private_key_name -T git@github.com`

You can also define you key in `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host github.com
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/private_key_name
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm using following commands.

```
git config -e  # update user mail etc.
git config user.email abc@abc.com
git config user.name abc
git commit --amend --reset-author
```

Comment: `user.name`/`user.email` are not credentials. They're commit identification data. They're used during commit creation and never used during `pull`/`push`. You show how to recreate a commit with new metadata but that doesn't help the OP because hist question is about SSH authentication.